# what is the maximum length of flowdocument pagewidth

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock, flowdocument

I have a `WPF` application that receive user text and scroll it in left direction.
for that I am using `Grid,TextBlock,Flowdocument,ThicknessAnimation`.`Flow document` is added to the text block through `inlines`,`textblock` is a child of `grid` and at the end `thicknessAnimation` scrolls the `grid`.here `flowdocument` is used for calculate the width of the text and it works fine with small input texts but when client enter large text it unable to find the length of the text.and if I assign hardcoded pageWidth to the the `flowdocument` it throw exception that `{"'1000001' is not a valid value for property 'PageWidth'."}` by random check I comes to a conclusion that **pagewidth should be less than 1000000**.
now my question is the 
1. how can i increase the page width
2. How can i find the proper width of text.

here is my code for finding length of text.

```
//INPUT TEXT LENGTH 1547081
double _flowDocFormattedTextLength = GetWidthOfText(this._flowDocument);
if (this._direction == "left")
    {
        this._tickerTxtBlk.Width = this._textTickerLength;
            this._tickerGrid.Width = this._textTickerLength;
            this._flowDocument.PageWidth = this._textTickerLength;

        this._ThickAnimGrid.From = new Thickness(this._width, 0, 0, 0);
        this._ThickAnimGrid.To = new Thickness(-(this._textTickerLength), 0, 0, 0);
    }

private double GetWidthOfText(FlowDocument fldoc)
        {
            double fontHeight = this._flowDocument.FontSize;
            double _flowDocFormattedText = new FormattedText(
                        GetText(this._flowDocument),
                        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                        this._flowDocument.FlowDirection,
                        new Typeface(this._flowDocument.FontFamily, this._flowDocument.FontStyle, this._flowDocument.FontWeight, this._flowDocument.FontStretch), this._flowDocument.FontSize,
                        this._flowDocument.Foreground).WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace;

            return _flowDocFormattedText;
        } 

private string GetText(FlowDocument doc)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (TextElement el in GetRunsAndParagraphs(doc))
    {
        Run run = el as Run;
        sb.Append(run == null ? Environment.NewLine : run.Text);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```